# How to install JDK and Intellij IDEA on ARM/Samsung series 3

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, arm, chromebook

So I am very, very new to Linux.  I am also new-ish to coding.  I'm currently learning Java and purchased a Samsung series 3 Chromebook for the sole purpose of practicing code (eventually moving to slick 3d).

I have JUST installed XFCE using crouton and have gotten Firefox using the Synaptic Package Manager, woohoo!

I would like to find out how/which JDK I need for this device and how to install Intellij IDEA.  I've tried searching around for a little while now and feel a bit overwhelmed with all the information regarding this, not only new OS, but new architecture (ARM).

Basically my main goals are to be able to get the proper JDK and a Java IDE up and running.  I have read that Intellij IDEA may or may not be available yet for the ARM processors in which case using Eclipse would be just as fine.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but just did this myself. Very simple really: Go to https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download for the latest version of idea. While it's downloading go to the terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Once Idea is downloaded and openjdk installed, extract the idea file somewhere.

```
mv ~/Downloads/idea-IU*.tar.gz ~
cd ~
tar xvf idea-IU*.tar.gz
```

To launch idea then just go to the extracted directory and run the idea.sh in the bin directory

```
cd idea-IU*/bin
./idea.sh
```

Should start up nicely

Update:

Saying it starts up nicely was not a lie. It just doesn't stay up long. Trying to see whats going wrong. Will update with findings.

OK, so you'll also need to do the following, open idea.sh and add -jamvm to the list of arguments used to run intellij,so change this line:

```
IDE_JVM_ARGS=""
```

To this:

```
IDE_JVM_ARGS="-jamvm"
```

ALSO, you'll need to install `clang` ( `sudo apt-get install clang` ) and copy and run ( `bash <scriptname>.sh /path/to/idea/bin` ) this guy's shell script : https://gist.github.com/pcarrier/7560053#file-fsnotifierto-sh

Answer (score 0):

OpenJDK is available in Ubuntu, and the Oracle Java SE Development Kit can be downloaded from Oracle. For the latter, you would need the "hard float ABI" version.

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/12/oracle-java-ppa-updated-with-arm-support.html might be a more user-friendly way than downloading the Oracle environment yourself.

Eclipse exists in Ubuntu too.